# Unexpected GitHub contributor: Is it a security breach? Can he / she change my files?

Tags: github, github-pages

This question may be off-topic, but I don't know where to ask, and I would appreciate very much some help. I can delete the question afterwards if needed.

I keep a lot statistics materials, and a website for my own consumption (a quick reference of materials I learn about) on GitHub. But I am definitely not a coder, or have a deep interest in the inner workings of what seems to be a great tool for professional collaboration.

Today I found that I have a "contributor". I never invited, know or expected any contributors. So two questions:

1. Is this a sign of some sort of security breach?
2. Can this person change my files without permission?

Here is what I see:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: can he/she change my files?
Yes, but not without you knowing about said change, and you can revert them.
You can see [terry21's change here](https://github.com/RInterested/statistics/commits/gh-pages?author=terry21).

Second, [`terry21`](https://github.com/terry21) does not seem to have any activity on his/her own, so a fork and pull request are not possible.

Maybe you did those commits with a `user.name` and `user.email` incorrectly set on one of your machines? That would be enough to make those commits appear as done by another account.

Comment: Yes, I have it set up to make commits from a computer that, although somewhat public, it is low risk. The dates match. However, I had made commits in the past from that computer, and the older ones show under my name. Would someone have change the git profile in the local computer? For what possible purpose?

Comment: @Toni maybe a simple mistake as a `git config user.name` made in the wrong folder.